Galois cohomology for non-Galois extensions
If $L/K$ is a Galois extension with group $G$ then we can consider $H^*(G;L^\times)$.  This is useful in algebraic number theory, and there are many results about it.
Now let $L/K$ be a finite separable extension that need not be Galois.  The tensor products $L\otimes_K\dotsb\otimes_KL$ form a cosimplicial ring $R^\bullet$, the unit groups form a cosimplicial abelian group $(R^\bullet)^\times$, this gives a cochain complex in the usual way, and we can write $HU^*(L/K)$ for the resulting cohomology groups.  In the Galois case it is not hard to show that $HU^*(L/K)=H^*(G;L^\times)$ (starting from the standard isomorphism $\phi\colon L\otimes_KL\to\text{Map}(G,L)$ given by $\phi(a\otimes b)(\sigma)=a\,\sigma(b)$).  The cosimplicial approach makes various functorial properties much more obvious than the group cohomology approach, however.  This is all surely well-known to many people.
Is there a convenient reference that shows which parts of class field theory etc remain true in this setting?  I know how to prove that $HU^1(L/K)=0$, for example. Given $K\leq L\leq M$ it is not hard to produce a sequence
$$ 0 \to HU^2(L/K) \to HU^2(M/K) \to HU^2(M/L), $$
and to prove that the composite is zero.  In the case where everything is Galois it is a standard fact that the sequence is exact.  I could probably generalise the proof but it would be nice if it was already written somewhere.  For a degree $n$ Galois extension of local fields it is known that $HU^2(L/K)\simeq\mathbb{Z}/n$.  I don't know whether that should still be true in the non-Galois case.  Some facts can be proved by reduction to the Galois case but it would feel more satisfying to prove them directly.

Where do you use separability? \ Is $H^1(L/K) = 0$ meant to be $HU^1(L/K) = 0$?

@LSpice Yes, I meant $HU^1(L/K)=0$, I have changed it.  The proof for that uses separability, but some other things work without it.

Maybe if you say "etale" instead of "Galois"? $Y=Spec(L)\to X=Spec(K)$ is an etale cover, and this leads to an augmented simplicial scheme made up of fiber products over $X$ of copies of $Y$. Then you evaluate a sheaf, such as the multiplicative sheaf, levelwise to get your augmented cosimplicial group. I'm just thinking that whatever reference you find might use these words.

(meant to say fiber products of copies of $Y$ over $X$, of course)

Don't know how much useful this might be but using Grothendieck's Galois theory one might switch to a category of finite $\hat G$-sets for (appropriately chosen) profinite group $\hat G$; I believe that since $L/K$ is finite $\hat G$ can actually be chosen finite. Now $L$ corresponds to a transitive $\hat G$-set of the form $\hat G/\hat H$, for some subgroup $\hat H\subset\hat G$ of finite index; and the cosimplicial object you consider corresponds to the simplicial $\hat G$-set with entries of the form $(\hat G/\hat H)^n$. This can be further simplified using the following fact:

For any $\hat G$-set $X$, $(\hat G/\hat H)\times X$ is isomorphic to $IU(X)$ where $U:\hat G\text{-sets}\to\hat H\text{-sets}$ is the restriction and $I:\hat H\text{-sets}\to\hat G\text{-sets}$ is its left adjoint. So that simplicial object is the "standard construction" for $I\dashv U$.

I'm just elaborating Tom Goodwillie's comment. Your complex is the Cech complex for the étale cover $\operatorname{Spec} L\to \operatorname{Spec} K$ with coefficients in the sheaf $\mathbb{G}_m$. The standard sources on étale cohomology for example by Deligne, in SGA41/2, or Milne, in his book or notes, would be good places to look for more details. (Milne says that your complex was first written down by Amitsur, so you might also look at references discussing of Amitsur cohomology.)

Indeed, it seems that "Amitsur cohomology" is the right thing to search for.  For example, there is the 1977 paper "Brauer groups and Amitsur cohomology for general commutative ring extensions" by Villamayor and Zelinsky (which I have not yet digested).

(On the other hand, I think that the standard references on étale cohomology are less useful, as they quickly pass to arbitrarily fine étale covers rather than considering a fixed cover.)

Another possibly useful keyword is "descent cohomology." Ultimately these are all special cases of monadic descent.
